# How do I modify the StyledEditorKit and override the defaultKeyTyped Action?

Tags: java, swing, oop

How do I modify the StyledEditorKit and override the defaultKeyTyped Action?
I've created a TextAction, and even extended the StyledEditorKit.  But how do I add the action to the list of actions inside of the extended StyledEditorKit though?

Ultimately I'm trying to override the defaultKeyTyped Action.  I can do this by adding a key Listener but shouldn't I do this with the Editor Kit instead?  Architecturally, this is closer to where actions performed for higher level actions are isn't it?  Whereas the addKeyListener is a lower level method?

Comment: `Ultimately I'm trying to override the defaultKeyTyped Action` - Why? What is your requirement?

Comment: @camickr - I want to search for regular expressions and highlight text based on those regular expressions after the space key is typed

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think that this is a proper use of an EditorKit. Better would be to use a DocumentListener or DocumentFilter depending on if you want to act on input prior to or after it being committed to the Document. Also, another option is to consider using an InputVerifier.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> I want to search for regular expressions and highlight text based on those regular expressions after the space key is typed

Myself I'd use a DocumentListener for this, but would be sure to turn the listener off when my code was making changes to the document, and then turn it back on again.

Comment: I want to search for regular expressions and highlight text based on those regular expressions after the space key is typed

Comment: So turning off the listener stops the application from freezing?  Because I see this in the tutorial for the DocumentListener:  "You may want to change the document's text within a document listener. However, you should never modify the contents of a text component from within a document listener. If you do, the program will likely deadlock. Instead, you can use a formatted text field or provide a document filter."

Comment: Do you have some code you can share on how to de-register the event listener before it makes modifications to the document?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some old code I found on the web a long time ago.

Paste some code in the top text area. Type the Regex into the text field. You can do the search either as you type or when you click the button depending on the state of the checkbox.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexKing implements ActionListener, DocumentListener
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new RegexKing();
    }

    public RegexKing()
    {
        initGUI();
        setupGUI();
        displayFrame();

    }

    public void initGUI()
    {
        // init
        frame = new JFrame("Regex King");
        container = new JPanel();

        inputArea = new JTextArea();
        regexField =new JTextField();
        outputArea = new JTextArea();

        quickMatch = new JCheckBox("Attempt Match on Change");
        matchButton = new JButton("Match");

        inputScroll = new JScrollPane(inputArea);
        outputScroll = new JScrollPane(outputArea);

        // setup
        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        matchButton.addActionListener(this);
        regexField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

        // key binding
        KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, Event.SHIFT_MASK, false);
        Action keyact = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                doMatch();
            }
        };

        container.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(key, "DO_MATCH");
        container.getActionMap().put("DO_MATCH", keyact);

    }

    public void setupGUI()
    {
        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        container.setLayout(gbl);

        setInsets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbcf = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        setComp(inputScroll, 10, 10, 20, 1, 1, 1);
        setComp(quickMatch, 10, 20, 1, 1, 1, .1);
        setComp(matchButton, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, .1);
        setComp(regexField, 10, 30, 20, 1, 1, .1);
        setComp(outputScroll, 10, 40, 20, 1, 1, 1);
    }

    public void setComp(JComponent comp, int gx, int gy, int gw, int gh, double wx, double wy)
    {
        gbc.gridx = gx;
        gbc.gridy = gy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gw;
        gbc.gridheight = gh;
        gbc.weightx = wx;
        gbc.weighty = wy;

        gbc.fill = gbcf;

        gbl.setConstraints(comp, gbc);
        container.add(comp);
    }

    public void setInsets(int top, int bottom, int left, int right)
    {
        gbc.insets.top = top;
        gbc.insets.bottom = bottom;
        gbc.insets.left = left;
        gbc.insets.right = right;
    }

    public void displayFrame()
    {
        frame.setContentPane(container);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        if(quickMatch.isSelected() == true)
        {
            doMatch();
        }
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        if(quickMatch.isSelected() == true)
        {
            doMatch();
        }
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)  {}


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getSource() == matchButton)
        {
            doMatch();
        }
    }

    public void doMatch()
    {
        outputArea.setText("\nAttempting Match...");
        inputArea.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();

        try
        {

            String inputText = inputArea.getText();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexField.getText());
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);

            int matchCount = 0;

            while(matcher.find())
            {

                matchCount++;
                outputArea.append("\n\nMatch #" + matchCount);

                for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount() + 1; i++)
                {
                    outputArea.append("\nGroup #" + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
                    outputArea.append(" , " + matcher.end(i));
                    int start = matcher.start(i);
                    int end = matcher.end(i);
                    System.out.println(start + " : " + end);
                    inputArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight( start, end, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter );

                    System.out.println(i);
                    if (matchCount == 1) inputArea.setCaretPosition(start);
                }

            }

        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            outputArea.append("\nEXCEPTION THROWN");
        }

        outputArea.append("\n\nFinished.\n");

    }

    GridBagLayout gbl;
    GridBagConstraints gbc;
    int gbcf;

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel container;

    JTextArea inputArea;
    JTextField regexField;
    JTextArea outputArea;

    JScrollPane inputScroll;
    JScrollPane outputScroll;

    JCheckBox quickMatch;
    JButton matchButton;

}
```

Comment: This is a SUPER COOL program.  Thank you so much!  I wish I could up vote it.  (I only have 1 reputation though.)  I do need to change the document though (underline - like a link would underline automatically).  I think the best way would be to use the addKeyListener method.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnByrne, upvoting is nice, but don't forget to accept answers that answer your question.